# Where to put content, in Installer project (WiX) or in code project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, wix

So I see two solutions to my current problem, but I was wondering what the pros and cons are, or if there is a defacto best practices approach.

So my current project has a number of configuration files, help files, and other external content.  I need this content local to run and debug the application. Currently we duplicate this content in a standard windows installer project.  This clearly is a bad idea. We are moving to a new setup that uses the WiX installer, and I'm currently setting the project up next to the code project and trying to figure the best way to share resources.  I see two solutions.

One is that I can put all the resources in the WiX project and then add them as links in the code project.  This way I know what I'm debugging is installer.

The other option would be to leave the content in the code project and path into it in the installer using the reference variables.

Right now it seems 6 one way, half dozen the other.  Any persuasive arguments for either method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that these configuration and help files are going to be installed in the same directory as the executables then definitely put them in the code project, mark them as Content, and add a reference to the code project to the installer project. If you're using WiX 3.5 the files will be automatically included in the installer along with the executables, which makes writing simple installers much easier.

For earlier versions of WiX or more complex deployment scenarios (where the content files could be going into different directories) you would still put them in the code project but then you'd use `File` elements with a relative path or reference variable in the `Source` attribute to include the the content files from the code project directory.

I don't believe that putting the content files in the WiX installer project directory instead of the code project directory will do anything to ensure that the version you use to debug will be the same as the version installed. That can only be ensured by thinking through the process of how your application finds these content files and making sure the right versions are found.

So going back to the simple case where the content is in the code project and marked as Content, and it will be installed and loaded from the same directory as the executables, then it is only a matter of setting "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always" or "Copy if newer" and then you can be sure the versions used in debugging and the version installed will match.